# Temporary stored procedure scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

`SQL Server` supports temporary tables(local and global).

Using dynamic-SQL (`EXEC` or `dbo.sp_executesql`) we could create new context and local temporary table is visible only in dynamic-SQL block but not outside.

```
-- Normal table
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE tab(i INT); INSERT INTO tab(i) VALUES (1)');
SELECT * FROM tab;

-- Global temporary table
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE ##tab(i INT); INSERT INTO ##tab(i) VALUES (2)');
SELECT * FROM ##tab;

-- Local temporary table
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #tab(i INT); INSERT INTO #tab(i) VALUES (3)');
SELECT * FROM #tab;
-- Invalid object name '#tab'.
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/VUGKO68165)**</kbd>

Now let's try the same with stored procedures:

```
-- Normal procedure
EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc AS SELECT 1 AS col;');
EXEC my_proc;

-- Global temporary procedure
EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE ##my_proc AS SELECT 2 AS col;');
EXEC ##my_proc;

-- Local temporary procedure
EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE #my_proc AS SELECT 3 AS col;');
EXEC #my_proc;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/SNBI75341)**</kbd>

The question is why local temporary procedure behaves differently and it is visible outside `EXEC`?

Comment: FYI: if object has entry in tempdb.sys.objects  ,we are able to see this even after scope.querying system catalogs may provide more info

Answer (score 0):

The reason it keeps it around  outside the exec because SQL Server can reuse the proc's query plan.

The proc disappears as soon as the session where it was defined (via the exec) is closed.

MS is very careful indicate that temp 'tables' (one with one # sign) are local to the context and not visible to calling program.

See:
Any tables you create are visible to the EXEC() context in

> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Could you provide exact quote from doc? `The reason it keeps it around outside the exec because SQL Server can reuse the proc's query plan. `What with SP that has `WITH RECOMPILE`?

Comment: The quote comes from the URL I cited and is in the section headed: EXEC() in a nutshell near the bottom of the cited page. Since SQL Server has established that it will keep the proc around as long as the calling guy is active using 'with recompile' will force SQL Server to recompile every time but it will still be accessible outside of the exec.